# JAAS authentication in jboss 7 using customloginmodule (DatabaseServerLoginModule)

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, single-sign-on, saml, jaas

I am trying to do authentication in spring mvc application using picketlink with jboss 7.

I have configured web.xml,jboss-web.xml,standalone.xml for custom login module,
picketlink-idfed.xml,picketlink-handlers.xml.

I have my customlogin module which extends Databaseserverloginmodule.

When I try to login I am getting blank page as 404 error and my customlogin module is not called as authentication  is not happening.

Am i missing any configuration?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I found a great example here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/creating-a-custom-jboss-login-module#